# Android: как провести сериализацию?

Tags: android, java, serializable, сериализация

Здраствуйте. Возникло срочное требование. Из гугла ничего не вынес толком.
У меня есть текстовый файл, который я заганяю в HashMap, через BUfferReader, таким методом.

```
try {
            AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
            InputStreamReader istream = new InputStreamReader(assetManager.open("dictionary.txt"));
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(istream);

            while ((word = in.readLine()) != null) {
                dictionary.put(word, 0);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // FileNotFoundExpeption       
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // IOExeption
        }
```

Подскажите как провести сериализацию, что бы его каждый раз не компилировать?
И как потом вытаскивать из него строки, если этот файл, словарь английских слов, а моя программа сравнивает строки и при необходимости редактирует, то есть проверка орфографии.
Спасибо.

Comment: а если это все загнать в базу? И при старте не загружать в память слова. Возможно выборка с базы будет хоть и медленнее выборки с словаря в памяти, но не настолько, что пользователь что то заметит.

В противном случае, придется делать свою структуру классов и свой формат файла, что бы обеспечить быстрый запуск.

Comment: @bboybboy Не понял из вопроса (особенно о том, какое возникло требование), что вы хотите сделать и зачем вам складывать слова в HashMap, при условии, что значение всегда 0. Что вы хотите сериализовать и зачем?

Comment: У меня есть словарь английских слов в *.txt файле, каждое слово = строка, которую я записую в HashMap. Программа - проверка орфаграфии. И вот когда на вход метода я подаю строку, она проверяется на наличие такое же в HashMap. Если нет, слово коректируется так, что строятся асе возможные релятивные варианты, которые также после каждого построения проверятся. 

Но процес проверки проходит долго, если ложить все в базу SQLite, и делать проверку выбркой, время на проверку потратится еще больше. Вот думаю что сериализация, мой выход из даной ситуации.

Comment: @bboybboy вы не поняли вопрос? Зачем вы используете HashMap, если ключем у вас является слово, а значением всегда 0? Или вы собираетесть изменять значение? Если нет, то вам будет достаточно HashSet.

Во-вторых, непонятно, что вы хотите сериализовать. Готовый HashMap?

Answer (score 2):

Предложу свой вариант, как бы я это оптимизировал. Он покажется диким,  но если нужна скорость, то приходиться иногда жертвовать красотой. (дальше по коду будут видны реальные числа - я просто нашел гуглом словарь английских слов на 349900 слов - для моих целей предостаточно).

Вначале нужно подготовить файл. (я предполагаю, что файл состоит из одиночных слов). Самое первое - сортируем слова в списке. Смотрим самое длинное слово. Скорее всего он не будет длиннее 16 символов. А теперь каждую строку добиваем пробелами до этой длины (на самом деле добивать нужно будет до 15, а то и 14  - у нас же есть переводы строк - в любом случае hex редактором проверяем, что каждое слово начинается с позиции, кратной 16).

Почему 16? Просто это число - степень двойки, что положительно скажется на производительности. Но может быть Вам подойдет 32 или 64. Но 64 - это уже очень много.

Файл теперь конечно станет больше (может даже в раза два).

Дальше загрузка. В коде создаем массив символов нужно размера (по размеру файла, количество_слов*16) и в один прием загружаем туда словарь. Это будет значительно быстрее, чем загрузка по одному слову. (Загрузка по одному слову в dict будет скорее всего иметь логарифмическую сложность. А этот способ - почти линейную).

Теперь нужно решить две задачи - поиск слова по индексу и поиск слова в словаре. Первая задача решается просто. Если знаем индекс, то просто умножаем его 16 и это будет индекс в массиве символов. Копируем 16 символов и отрезаем по конечному пробелу.

Поиск слова в словаре - также не сложно. На первый взгляд может показаться, что нужно пробегать по всему списку (а это долго). Но я не даром писал, что список нужно отсортировать. В этом случае можно применить бинарный поиск. Но так как это словарь, то можно применить более хитрый способ - индекс. Такой файл можно подготовить заранее - пробегаем по всему списку слов и выписываем номера строк, в которых изменяются первые две буквы. Для английского это будет 676 строк вида

```
aa 0
ab 82
ac 1216
ad 2904
...
zz 349895
```

(но там будет только 635, 41 комбинация не встречается). Самые популярные комбинации - ca, re, ma, co un (по нарастанию).
для русского - чуть больше 1000 (33*33 = 1089, но я не помню слов для комбинаций ъъ или ыъ. Но с индекса исключать не стоит).
Поиск будет значительно быстрее - так как сразу находим небольшой участок. ( у меня получилось, что самый большой участок - `un` - 11780 слов 115 комбинаций больше 1000 слов.

Дальше об оптимизациях. Если посмотреть на статистику, то слов, которые короче 8 символов достаточно много - порядка 40 процентов. Поэтому можно разбить слова на две группы - те, которые влазят в 8 символов и те, которые влазят в 16 (тут же и группу на 32, но я таких слов не нашел:) ). А в индексе писать нужно будет ещё и номер группы.

Как это реализовывать в коде - я оставлю на самостоятельную работу.

Comment: Я бы тогда предложил использовать сжатое префиксное дерево. Конечно слова не будут доступны по индексу, но такого требования и нет в исходной задаче. Поиск будет иметь логарифмическую сложность, данные будут храниться довольно компактно.

Comment: сложность то может и логарифмичская, но не факт, что поиск будет быстрее. Но моя реализация на самом то деле ставит себе задачу - сделать быструю загрузку.